# Threejs - Translate object based on quaternion rotation

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, three.js

I have an object that is using a quaternion.  This quaternion gets updated on a user's keypress to allow the object to rotate it's internal axis.  The rotations are working fantastic.  When in it's default state (before a user adjusts the rotation) my quaternion reads w:1, x:0, y:0, z:0

I want this object to always move forward in space via it's internal z-axis - THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1).  How can I use the quat to know where it's z-axis is and move it forward?

For example - when my quaternion reads w:0.7, x:0.7, y:0, z:0 - the object is rotated to have it's z-axis pointed upward.  Is there a way to move an object via it's internal axis?

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://bitly.com/RXPy5w - I want the square to always move forward in relation to it's z-axis

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Three.js R55 and later:

Renamed Quaternion methods:
        .multiply() to .multiplyQuaternions()
        .multiplySelf() to .multiply()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is add the following line in your render loop:

```
airplane.translateZ( 1 );
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8gH/21/  Enjoy!

And by the way, you can't "translate a quaternion". Keep studying until you understand what this code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

A quaternion here represents a rotation in three-space. You need to first specify what initial orientation you're rotating from. Make that a unit vector in the direction of your starting orientation.

Now, to travel in the direction of your current orientation, you can rotate the initial-orientation vector through the rotation described by your current quaternion. Now you have a unit vector pointing in the right direction.

Finally, of course, you can scale that unit vector to represent a motion by a non-unit distance, add it to your current position, and you're done.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to take a look.  Could you please be more specific about "you can rotate the initial-orientation vector through the rotation described by your current quaternion."  If I make a vector (0,0,-1) as it's initial direction - how would I go about rotating it based on the quat?  Any pseudo code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know three.js in particular, but a glance at the documentation suggests that you want `quat.multiplyVector3(initialVec, currentVec)`.

Comment: Based on this suggestion I've created two variables: var initialVec = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1); var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); and I'm doing matrix.multiplyVector3(initialVec, object.quaternion) - however I don't understand how a resulting matrix can be used as a vector to translate my objects position.  It seems multiplyVector3 is part of the Matrix4 object and can't be done through a Vector3 object... Sorry  for being very newbish here, but I'm thinking that I'm not understanding the implementation of this.  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you got the wrong multiplyVector3? My reading of the docs is there's a function by that name on quaternion objects too.